# Devices with user re-writable MAC addresses

Tags: network-adapter, mac-address

I'm looking for routers, cell phones, Internet sticks etc. that have user modifiable MAC addresses. Does anyone know how to spot them?? Also how to write the MAC address.. I've heard Linux is a good OS for performing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [Nokia N900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N900) lets you do this using macchanger as its running a version of Linux called Maemo. [Android phones](http://www.techknow.me/forum/index.php?topic=4902.0) let you change the mac address, especially if you've rooted the device but it depends on the hardware, google it before you buy one. It looks like it was at least possible to do so on [iPhones](http://www.ifans.com/forums/threads/guide-how-to-spoof-your-mac-address.35210/) but this may only apply to pre IOS 4 phones. Check before you buy. Obviously i cant list through every phone and software configuration for you (feel free to suggest a specific phone + software version however).

On most versions of Linux, its easiest to grab a copy of [macchanger](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/macchanger-utility-for-manipulating-the-mac-address-of-network-interfaces-included-gui-utility.html) and run it up. If your router supports [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) (the open source router firmware) then [its possible](http://www.ehow.com/how_8540362_change-mac-address-ddwrt.html) to change your MAC address on it as well.

Comment: Do u know if any newer cell phones have this feature??

Comment: @Tonyalmeida hopefully that clears it up, please mark it as answered if it's what you were looking for! Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

I've never met a router incapable of this. Dunno how it is with other devices though.

Comment: Yeah I was told that the newer routers these days generally have the option.. Thanks for comfirming..